# If you already have a copy of the code, is there any reason to create a feature branch?

Tags: version-control, ide

Let's say you join a team and are provided with a copy of the code from a project. That code is already set up in your IDE. Someone tells you that you need to create a feature branch. Isn't the copy you have already a feature branch? What would happen if you took the steps to create a feature branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are asked to create a feature branch, do that. If you already have code in your IDE, you may have the main branch. Creating a branch, you'll create a copy of the code separate from the main branch, then make your commits to that feature branch.